# How to change the keymap of a Bluetooth keyboard of iPad?

Tags: ios, keyboard, bluetooth

I have a Logitech K480 Bluetooth keyboard. I want to map the <kbd>caps lock</kbd> key to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>. What should I do?

Comment: I've not heard of any way to do such things on an iPad.  You might check the app store for 3rd party keyboards to see if anyone has produced an app.  I'm not sure that any current app even addresses the bluetooth layouts in addition to the touch screen ones.

Answer (score 2):

This is not currently possible

Comment: Still not possible in 2/18 as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

It works in 2020
With iOS and iPadOS 13.4+ you can modify the four modifier keys:

- Caps Lock (⇪)
- Control (⌃)
- Option (⌥)
- Command (⌘)

You can choose from:
Caps Lock, Ctrl, Option, Command, Escape, and Globe.

I have no BT Keyboard, but the settings are there.
The source I found this:
https://www.idownloadblog.com/2020/03/05/ipad-keyboard-modifier-keys-tutorial/

1. Open the Settings app on your device with iOS or iPadOS 13.4 or later.
2. Choose General from the main list.
3. Tap Keyboard.
4. Choose the option Hardware Keyboard.

If you don’t see the option: Verify that your external keyboard is indeed connected to your iPad.

5. Now tap Modifier Keys.
6. Choose any listed modifier key to change its behavior.

(My very first post on a Stack Exchange site. Hop I can finally help others)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. And well done! Thanks for contributing

Answer (score 1):

I am also missing this functionality. I mainly use a HHKB Pro 2 keyboard, and I remap my other keyboards to a similar layout (Ctrl where Caps Lock usually is, and backspace right above Enter).

Some applications may allow simply key-mapping functionality, e.g., Blink Shell (specifically, it is possible swap Ctrl and Caps Lock on a keyboard with a regular layout).

Comment: Does Blink Shell actually let you modify the behavior of a hardware keyboard?  I don't know of any other app which does that.

Comment: @TomGewecke I just double-checked with a cheap Microsoft keyboard in the office (connected via Apple's Camera Adapter). Yes, it allows modification of the keyboard layout when a hardware keyboard is connected. Very handy in my opinion.